# Are there any disadvantages of using very low "rate" value for Linux HTB queuing discipline?

Tags: tc

I have a use-case where egress traffic on 10Mbps connection needs to be divided into two classes. First class is *high-priority* traffic which needs to be able to use bandwidth up to 10Mbps. Second class is *low-priority* traffic which can use the amount of bandwidth left from the *high-priority* traffic. I could do this in a following way:

```
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 10mbps ceil 10mbps
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 10mbps ceil 10mbps
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:11 htb rate 1kbps ceil 10mbps
```

*High-priority* traffic is filtered to class with handle `1:10` and *low-priority* traffic is filtered to class with handle `1:11`. As seen above, *low-priority* traffic has only 1kbps guaranteed traffic and it has to "borrow" traffic from the parent(`1:`) if it has bandwidth to spare.

However, this `1kbps` seems like an hack. Are there any disadvantages of using very low "rate" value for Linux HTB queuing discipline? Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: You will have problems with latency. However that is what tests are for